# Clasificar a partir de un arreglo de objetos

Tags: java, array, objeto

a partir de un arreglo de personas generadas al azar tengo que clasificarlas después en otros 3 arreglos de acuerdo a su edad: los menores de son los que tienen menos de 18, los adultos los que tienen entre 18 y 69 y los ancianos los mayores de 70, pero he estado teniendo problemas para hacerlo. Agradecería si puedieran ayudarme con esto

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Persona[] personas = new Persona[100] ;
    Persona[] menores = new Persona[100];
    Persona[] adultos = new Persona[100];
    Persona[] ancianos = new Persona[100];

     for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
     {
         personas[i] = new Persona (generadorId(100000000, 999999999), generadorEdad(0,100));
     }
```

Comment: Y cuales son los rangos de edad para su clasificación

Comment: Disculpa, olvidé colocarlos. Ya los agregué al enunciado.

Comment: Luis dime si la respuesta te fue util

Comment: Lo hice así, pero al momento de mostrar los valores aparece como si los datos de los arreglos estuvieran nulos, incluso el arreglo original

Comment: Pero te da error? Tu inicializas correctamente los objetos? Mi codigo parece estar bien. Tu tienes mas codigo q no pusiste aqui?

Comment: Si tu arreglo de personas no tiene objetos personas inicializados dentro de el todo sera nulo revisa si tu creas personas dentro del arreglo

Comment: Después de revisarlo de nuevo vi que había colocado mal la excepción para manejar los valores nulos, pero ahora ya está funcionando sin problemas, muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int contMenores = 0;    
int contAdultos = 0;
int contAncianos = 0;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   if(personas[i]!=null)
   {
      if(personas[i].Edad <= 18)
      {
         menores[contMenores] = personas[i];
         contMenores++;
      }
      else if(personas[i].Edad > 18 && personas[i].Edad <= 69)
      {
         adultos[contAdultos] = personas[i];
         contAdultos++;
      }
      else if(persona[i].Edad] >=70)
      {
         ancianos[contAncianos] = personas[i];
         contAncianos++;
      }
   }
}
```

Se declaran **3** **variables**, para ir contando la cantidad de **menores**, **adultos** y **ancianos**, y guardarlos en esa posición en el arreglo que corresponda.

Posteriormente se hace un **ciclo for** que recorrerá el arreglo de personas e irá preguntando en que grupo de edad se encuentra dicha persona para guardarla en el arreglo que corresponda.